# How to fix CORS error on 3rd party API call in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, cors, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am working on Nuxt 3 with `useFetch` hook to call API. When I call the 3rd party API post `https://apitest.bankfeeds.com.au/v1/customer/data` using useFetch hook, it returns the CORS error

> CORS Missing Allow Origin

I have the ssr: false in my `nuxt.config.ts` file

[image: check error here]

I have tried to set cors on nuxt config file but not working and returns the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: looks like makes sense but I want this on nuxt 3 so how can I configure the origin proxy policy to call 3rd party API with front end only? Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably giving you a CORS error because you are fetching the API through the browser and not trough the backend.

Most third party API's deny cross-origin requests.

Try fetching the API from postman, if it works just put the fetch call in the server-side backend.

Comment: Yes in postmen it working fine. but I am using useFetch without any backend can you help me how can I sort out this without backend?

Comment: You have to call the `useFetch` in backend. You can follow the docs [here](https://www.nuxtjs.cn/guides/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook) on how to make it server-side.

Comment: seems there is vue or nuxt 2 code not the nuxt 3 latest versions. Do you mean that I need to use server side rendering to use this?

Comment: Yes. You have to use ssr or choose to integrate a different/separate backend. Sorry for the reference to the guide (didn’t notice it’s outdated)

Comment: ok thanks for your revert on this. I'll use the backend API and call this from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Use server/api folder to avoid such problems. This way you don't have to lose the benefits of useFetch composable. Make your requests server-to-server via Nitro.

api/server/auth.post.js

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body = await readBody(event);
  const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();

  try {
    await $fetch(`${runtimeConfig.public.apiBase}/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: { username: body.username, password: body.password },
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw createError({
      message: "Authorization Failed",
      statusCode: 401,
    });
  }

  return {
    message: "success",
  };
});
```